# How to keep alive the VPN connection?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm using NetworkManager and OpenVPN on linux.

The problem is I get random disconnections, especially when idle.

So I was thinking maybe there was an option to keep it alive. I have seen examples for OpenVPN config files, but I don't think I'm using one. I have set up everything directly from the NetworkManager. I found the NetworkManger config file for my current connection, and it has these sections: [connection], [vpn], and [ipv4]. Does any of those have a keepalive option? What's the syntax, and how does it work?

Comment: You might want to show us the logs of your VPN connection, both server and client. OpenVPN indeed has a `keepalive` option, but NM GUI has no way to pass the parameters, so you might want to hack into the global OpenVPN configuration, but I didn't find one, so it may be hard coded into NM.

Comment: If you're using a shell only, I'd suggest the use of `screen` or `tmux` so a disconnect doesn't hurt that much anymore.

Answer (score 21):

According to the [documentation here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html), the KeepAlive parameter is probably what you were looking for.

> # The keepalive directive causes ping-like
>    # messages to be sent back and forth over
>    # the link so that each side knows when
>    # the other side has gone down.
>    # Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
>    # peer is down if no ping received during
>    # a 120 second time period.
>    keepalive 10 120

This should either be added to the OpenVPN connection profile as a new line, or to the Advanced Configuration on the server (likely `/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf`).

Answer (score -3):

Insert on the client:

```
keepalive 10 60
```

This will keep your connection up.

Comment: Please provide more details for your answer.  Where does that get inserted?  What does it do?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but seriously, where do I insert that line?

Comment: insert into the config file on client side. On linux, located /etc/openvpn/client.conf

Comment: keepalive is a server side directive, not a client one.

Comment: @JamesWhite That is not exactly true.  `This option can be used on both client and server side, but it is enough to add this on the server side as it will push appropriate --ping and --ping-restart options to the client` I pasted this info [from here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/#:~:text=%2D%2Dkeepalive%20interval%20timeout,restart%20options%20to%20the%20client.)

Answer (score -3):

You have to do it each time you start up but what is wrong with just setting up ping xx - t in a terminal window.
Its low overhead and certainly fixes my problems in Windows 10 VPN which is locked down to a 30 minute idle timeout.